# WebAssembly runtime file into ValidationCode

Tags: rust, wasm, subxt, metadata

I have a CLI tool that gets a [WebAssembly runtime file](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/connect-a-local-parachain/#prepare-the-parachain-collator):

```rs
let validation_code_content = fs::read_to_string(path_validation_code)
        .expect("Should have been able to read the validation code file");
```

If I print `validation_code_content` I can see the content is correct. Now I want to send this file into an extrinsic (e.g: [register](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/common/src/paras_registrar.rs#L232)), which needs to be converted into the `[ValidationCode][3]` struct:

```rs
/// Parachain validation code.
#[derive(
    PartialEq,
    Eq,
    Clone,
    Encode,
    Decode,
    RuntimeDebug,
    derive_more::From,
    TypeInfo,
    Serialize,
    Deserialize,
)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Hash))]
pub struct ValidationCode(#[serde(with = "bytes")] pub Vec<u8>);
```

I can see in the [tests](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/common/src/paras_registrar.rs#L883) on the pallet that I need a vector of bytes:

```rs
fn test_validation_code(size: usize) -> ValidationCode {
        let validation_code = vec![0u8; size as usize];
        ValidationCode(validation_code)
}
```

So my approach is convert the String in the vector of bytes and cast it to ValidationCode:

```rs
    let validation_code = validation_code_content.into_bytes()
    let call = Call::Registrar(RegistrarCall::register {
        id: RococoId(para_id),
        genesis_head: HeadData(genesis_head),
        validation_code: ValidationCode(validation_code),
    });
```

The code compiles but the extrinsic fails because something is wrong with the validation code. Did I lose data when I am doing the conversion?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I see the event PvfCheckRejected

Comment: Sounds like the validation code is maybe wrong? Probably because you read the validation code as string and then convert it to bytes. Use `fs::read` to directly read it as binary data.

Comment: I tried with fs::read first and I was getting the PvfCheckRejected too

Comment: Are you sure that the wasm file is correct?

Comment: Yes, I tried with PolkadotJS and I can see the PvfCheckAccepted event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, as suspected was related to the conversion of the WASM file. Checking how the WASM runtime file is generated [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/parachain/test-parachains/adder/collator/src/main.rs#L45):

```rs
Some(cli::Subcommand::ExportGenesisWasm(_params)) => {
            let collator = Collator::new();
            println!("0x{:?}", HexDisplay::from(&collator.validation_code()));

            Ok(())
}
```

The first thing that has to be done is remove the `0x` in the file, an easy way to do it is deleting the first 2 characters:

```rs
validation_code.remove(0);
validation_code.remove(0);
```

And as seen in the code, the format of the file is `hex`, so importing the hex library in the Cargo and decoding the hex will make the proper conversion to bytes.

```rs
let code = hex::decode(validation_code).expect("Decoding failed"):
```

And now with the cast `ValidationCode(code)` it works in the extrinsic.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with your call data.

I don't know which client you are using.

I guess you need to write something like this:

```rs
RegistrarCall::register {
    id: RococoId(para_id),
    genesis_head: HeadData(genesis_head),
    validation_code: ValidationCode(validation_code),
}.encode()
```

Or

```rs
RegistrarCall::register {
    id: RococoId(para_id).encode(),
    genesis_head: HeadData(genesis_head).encode(),
    validation_code: ValidationCode(validation_code).encode(),
}
```

Comment: Sorry I skip some parts of the code to only focus on this call construction,I am using subxt and after it I construct the transaction propertly.

Comment: You shouldn't need to call `.encode()` on any of the "inner" things I think; just the outermost call (ie the top option here). But I'd need to be able to reproduce the issue with a complete code sample to be much help here I think.